# Android Studio menu icons are not the color they should be

Tags: java, android-studio, android-layout, android-bottomnavigationview

So I've created a bottom navigation bar with my custom icons. In the XML you can see how the icons look by default and I want that they look the same in my navigation bar.

[image: My navigation bar XML]

This is how the icons look after launching the app. It seems that they inherit a different design. How can I change that?

[image: App]

Comment: This might help you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51983273/how-to-show-menu-item-icon-without-tint-color-in-bottomnavigationview